# Is there any specific reason that a function call should not be used for a variable initializer in C

Tags: c, function, variables, coding-style

I am reading multiple style guides trying to standardize my programming style. While reading the FreeBSD and OpenBSD style guides on KNF, I noticed the following paragraph to be rather confusing.

> Be careful not to obfuscate the code by initializing variables in the declarations. Use this feature only thoughtfully. DO NOT use function calls in initializers!

Is there a technical reason that function calls should not be used when initializing data?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a technical reason that function calls should not be used when initializing data?

Function calls not only should not, but *cannot* be used to initialize static variables or variables declared at file scope.  They can, however, be used to initialize automatic variables inside functions.  The semantics of doing this are well defined, so I don't think there is a *technical* reason why such initializations should be avoided.

I take the rationale behind this style rule to be given by the first sentence of the quotation:

> Be careful not to obfuscate the code by initializing variables in the declarations.

The authors of the style guide evidently consider use of initializers to be potentially obfuscatory, and I take their emphasis in the last sentence to indicate that they think using function calls for initialization to be definitely obfuscatory.

For what it's worth, I disagree with those style guidelines.  According to me, variables generally *should* be initialized in their declarations if in fact there is a meaningful, semantically correct value for them at that point, and if that value can be conveniently expressed via an initializer.  I also have no general objection to function calls in initializers.  In particular, I would typically revise this:

```
void foo(void) {
    int result;
    result = do_something();
    // ...
}
```

to this:

```
void foo(void) {
    int result = do_something();
    // ...
}
```

.  I think the latter is actually slightly clearer, and I value that it has one fewer line.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the language rule from its creators. They just did not like this, and they were thinking that the code executed before the main will be too complicated and too long.

BTW many implementations provide mechanisms to execute some user code before main. gcc it is `__attribute__((constructor))`, but of course it is an extension.

Comment: I'm not seeing how a prohibition on functions being called by initializers (in C) can be about code that runs before `main()`.  You don't need any kind of style rule for that, since the language itself does not permit function calls in the initializers of any other than automatic variables (and those don't run before `main()`).